# Cannot read property of undefined when passing Static property values to class definition in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was was wondering whether someone could give some help with a peculiar problem that I am having in ExtJS 4. I have a defined a store that takes some of the values that I have specified in the 'read' and 'create' properties of the api object in the proxy from a class where these values are defined in the statics section of the class. However, when I run the app, I keep getting the error:

`**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Url' of undefined**.`

Here is the store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.address.AddressStore',
       {
           extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
           model: 'MyApp.model.address.AddressModel',
           requires: ['MyApp.props.Url'],
           proxy: {
               type: 'ajax',
               api: {
                   create: MyApp.props.Url.Address.ADD_ADDRESS_URL, //This is defined in the static class below
                   read: MyApp.props.Url.Address.GET_ALL_ADDRESSES_URL //As is this

               },
               reader: {
                   type: 'json',
                   root: 'Addresses'
               }
           }
       }

      );
```

Heres is the the class that defines the static properties MyApp.props.Url

```
Ext.define('MyApp.props.Url', {
    statics: {
        Address: {
           ADD_ADDRESS_URL: 'Address/AddAddress',
           GET_ALL_ADDRESSES_URL: 'Address/GetAllAddresses',
           GET_ALL_ADDRESS_TYPES_URL: 'Address/GetAllAddressTypes'
        }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the evaluation order of the code. In this case, you're essentially saying:

`Ext.define('MyClassName', o);`

The class definition only gets passed to `define` once the whole object is resolved. This means that the requires are only processed once we get inside the `define` call.

You need to do something like:

```
Ext.require('MyApp.props.Url', function() {
    console.log(MyApp.props.Url.Address.ADD_ADDRESS_URL);
    Ext.define('MyClass', {});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is sort of answer that I wanted (i.e. an explanation of what the problem could be and not simply the answer). I will test your solution tomorrow and will mark it as the correct answer if it indeed is the right answer. In the mean time, I will just upvote it.

Comment: Hi Evans, you are right. I just tested this and it works now. The requires should have enclosed the class that uses the static  props. Thanks for the help. Will Mark this as the correct answer